# Is it possible to change the .so file code in android studio itself and make a build?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, tensorflow, .so

I added one .so file in android studio project,I am able to see the code what they have written inside that .so file like .cc and .h files.So if I change that .cc file, is it directly creates an .so file dynamically. or after we have done all changes can we reload the .so file with new changes.

How can I create an .so file from another.so file libraries.any other way to use .so file like extracting those and adding to the android code.How can use already generated .so file with make changes.

**Is there any chance like making changes in .so file .cc files and compiling and running, if it is possible then how can run that .so file with my .cc file changes in android studio.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added one .so file in android studio project,I am able to see the code what they have written inside that .so file like .cc and .h files.So if I change that .cc file, is it directly creates an .so file dynamically. or after we have done all changes can we reload the .so file with new changes.

Neither. A .so file per se doesn't know the paths to headers and libraries it depends on, so it can't recompile itself.

> How can I create an .so file from another.so file libraries.

By reverse engineering.

> Is there any chance like making changes in .so file .cc files and compiling and running, if it is possible then how can run that .so file with my .cc file changes in android studio.

The chances are minimal. This approach will not succeed due to the absence of dependency information of the .so file.